# how to design LPH and HPF from APF

Tags: matlab, filter-design, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter, allpass

I came across a concept that says we can design LPH and HPF from APF when the transfer function of the two APFs given as

$$\begin{align}A_0(z)&=1\\
A_1(z)&=\frac{-a+z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\\\
H_{LP}(z)&=A_0(z)+A_1(z)\\
H_{HP}(z)&=A_0(z)-A_1(z)\end{align}$$

i tried to implement this in matlab but i did not get the desired frequency response..kindly help me with the matlab code for the same..

Comment: Your A1 formula is ambiguous. Please add more () to make clear what you divide by which (come on, this is basic "how to write down a formula").

Comment: i didnt understand what is the ambiguity in A1..are you asking me the value for a??

Comment: With Gilles edit, it's now clear that you meant A1 = (-a+z^(-1))/(1-az^(-1)) with your formula, and not A1= -a + (z^(-1))/(1-az^(-1)), which obviously is something completely different!

Comment: *but i did not get the desired frequency response*: What did you get instead? Where's your Matlab code? Please make it easy to answer your question!

Comment: Does your title *how to design LPH and HPF from APF* really reflect your question well? I feel your question is about understanding and analyzing the resulting filter, not designing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't say what response you're *actually* getting from Matlab, this is all guesswork.

So let's do the basics: A little formula juggling.

$$\begin{align}A_0(z)&=1\\
A_1(z)&=\frac{-a+z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\[4em]
H_{LP}(z)&=A_0(z)+A_1(z)\\
   &= 1 + \frac{-a+z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\
   &= \frac{{1-az^{-1}}-a+z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\
   &= \frac{(1-a)\quad +\quad (1-a)z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\[4em]
H_{HP}(z)&=A_0(z)-A_1(z)\\
   &= 1 - \frac{-a+z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\
   &= \frac{{1-az^{-1}}+a-z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}\\
   &= \frac{(1+a)\quad +\quad (-1-a)z^{-1}}{1-az^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

So, taken from these formulas, the filter coefficients for $H_{LP}$ are $b=[1-a,1-a]$, $a=[1,-a]$, and  for $H_{HP}$ it's $b=[1+a,-1-a]$, $a=[1,-a]$ for the canonical form of recursive filters

$$H= \frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^N b_i z^{-i}}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^M a_i z^{-i}}\text.$$

Plugging that into scipy's `scipy.signal.freqz` for different $a$ yielded (abscissa: normalized frequency $\in[0,\pi[$, ordinate: magnitude):

$H_{LP,a}$ for $a\in\{0,0.1,\dots,0.9,1\}$:

[image: LPFs]

$H_{HP,a}$ for $ a\in\{0,0.1,\dots,0.9,1\}$:

[image: HPFs]

which both very nicely match the terms low and high pass filters, respectively.

Comment: what is that scipy.signal.freqz..i didnt find that function in matlab documentation..

Comment: unfortunately i am not able to copy the matlab code which i wrote..i have used the coefficients which you suggested but though i am getting the response. its not varying when i change the parameter a..

Comment: here is my mail id: pavansunder@gmail.com..Would you kindly send me the matlab code..thanks :)

Comment: @pavansunder: why can't you share your Matlab code? This sounds like the lamest excuse to get someone else to do your homework ever.

Comment: i tried to copy and paste my matlab code....but was unable to do..can u share your mail id so that i ll send my code..

Comment: being successful at "copy and paste" is, I'm afraid, the basic ability you will have when trying to succeed in perusing dsp.SE.

Comment: here is the code i wrote in matlab: a=0.2
num_LPF=[1-a 1-a]; 
den_LPF=[1 -a]
figure;
freqz(num_LPF,den_LPF);

Comment: @pavansunder ah nevermind. Just read the `freqz` documentation in matlab. What happens when you call `freqz` with two arguments? Hint: you should be using three arguments.

Comment: oh k i ll try using 3 arguments..btw i have uploaded the image in imgur..

Comment: @pavansunder: to be completely honest, I will end our discussion here.

Comment: ok anyways thanks for your help..i just wanna ask did you see the image which i have uploaded??

Comment: @pavansunder how should I, you did not post the link to the image.

Comment: @pavansunder also, as your two-argument `freqz` call is flawed, it's relatively meaningless, unless you use three arguments.

Comment: Oh i am sorry here is the link: http://imgur.com/YSqZSRM what is the third argument which i have to use...plz bear with me i may be asking very silly questions..i am new to this subject and still learning so i need little help..sorry for taking your time..:)

Comment: @pavansunder I can't take the effort of writing your matlab code off your shoulders. Read `freqz` documentation yourself. Matlab has **very** good documentation.