# Fine tuning LPF responses from cascading APFs

Tags: frequency-response, allpass

I would use this post to outline my question since the post had laid down the groundwork:

[how to design LPH and HPF from APF](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28309/how-to-design-lph-and-hpf-from-apf)

So if want to fine tune overall LPF response with more cascading allpass filter to realize $A_1(z)$ while keeping $A_0(z)$ as a delay line, are there Matlab or Python functions doing that? I assume $A_0(z)$ would be a programmable delay line, corresponding to the number of allpass filters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this only works with odd-order Butterworth filters. You don't have a choice of all pass filters: they are simply determined by the pole locations of the Butterworth. An adjustable delay line won't help here.

Comment: There is a theory of filter design where every occurrence of $z^{-1}$ is replaced by an APF such as $\frac{1+p\,z^{-1}}{1-p\,z^{-1}}$ .

Comment: Don't know what "don't have a choice of all pass filters" means. You can pick either first-order or second-order APF. I think you referred to $A_1(z)$ as an odd-order Bufferworth filter which can be decomposed into cascading APFs. Correct me if I misunderstood. There are other types can be decomposed too. But regardless, my question is the other way around that pick AFPs first then decide overall response, not decomposing a known LPF response. Say you just pick multiple cascading APFs in $A_1(z)$, my question was how to control overall frequency response.